# Play Framework 2.5 Form submit using POST method Error

Tags: java, forms, post, playframework-2.5

I have new to **Play Framework 2.5**. I am using Play in **Java**. Created a normal **HTML** form and want to **submit the form using POST** method but it throws error. I googled a lot but not succeed.

**routes:**

```
POST     /output     controllers.HomeController.result
```

**HTML Code:**

```
    <form name="form1" action="/output" method="post">
        <div id="content">
            <label>Enter Sentence/Paragraph.</label></br>
            <textarea id="para" name="para" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea></br>
            <input id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
package controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;
import views.html.output;.

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    @Inject
    FormFactory formFactory;

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("NLP Pipeline."));
    }

    public Result result() {
        DynamicForm requestData = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
        System.out.println("form: " + requestData.get("para"));
        return ok();
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
Unexpected exception
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
  at play.data.format.Formatters.<init>(Formatters.java:31)
  at play.data.format.FormattersModule.bindings(FormattersModule.java:18):
Binding(class play.data.format.Formatters to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.data.format.Formatters
    for parameter 1 at play.data.FormFactory.<init>(FormFactory.java:25)
  at play.data.FormFactoryModule.bindings(FormFactoryModule.java:17):
Binding(class play.data.FormFactory to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.data.FormFactory
    for field at controllers.HomeController.formFactory(HomeController.java:16)
  while locating controllers.HomeController
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:32)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
```

I want to use normal **HTML form** to submit request using **POST** method. Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the solution of my answer.

We can get the form **post data** in **Play framework 2.5** by

```
final Map<String, String[]> form_values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
```

and then get the **form name parameter value** by:

```
form_values.get("<key_name>")[0];
```

Comment: It worked for me also. Thanks iNikkz. It was a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply use helpers in your html code? Using

```
@import helper._

@form(my.controller.method.handling.post(param)) {
    <div id="content">
        <label>Enter Sentence/Paragraph.</label></br>
        <textarea id="para" name="para" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea></br>
        <input id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

Then, in the controller:

```
final Form<MyObject> form = formFactory.form(MyObject.class).bindFromRequest();
```

You'd just have to create a simple bean class of the form (to be filled in by Play with submitted data):

```
public class MyObject {
    private String para;
    public String getPara() { return para; }
    public void setPara(String para) { this.para = para; }
}
```

Way easier to handle form objects without dealing with type casting and so forth (see play documentation at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Handling-form-submission)